# Why can't I install Ubuntu to dual-boot on the HP Pavilion DM1 laptop?

Tags: hp

How come I don't get the automatic partition slider when I attempt to install Ubuntu 12.04 alongside Windows 7 on this machine?

http://www.gadgetreview.com/2011/07/hp-pavilion-dm1z-lm829av-11-6-inch-notebook-370-after-coupon-code.html

I have tried installation from a USB as well as CD. I tried installing Ubuntu 11.10 as well. I have futilely tried to manually partition the drive using info posted in the forums - 4 times. Each time, I just ended up spending countless hours reinstalling Windows 7!

Hence, I would greatly appreciate it if someone out there in Ubuntu land can post a wiki on how to access the partition slider when installing Ubuntu 12.04 alongside Windows 7 on THIS machine!

Alternatively, perhaps someone can post a partition scheme that will work on THIS machine? When I installed Ubuntu on my other laptop, the slider came up and partition was easy as pie!

Thanks in advance to whoever can help me solve this!!!

Comment: Which slider exactly are you talking about? Which forum posts have you been referencing? What are the exact steps you are taking to attempt install? What exactly is the problem you're encountering that's causing you to have to reintall Windows? Providing as much detail as you can is always helpful. Some generic advice: Install windows before you install Ubuntu. Windows likes to blow away grub. If you are having partition difficulties, try using gparted from the live cd. It never ceases to amaze me how well it works.

Comment: Can you define that **Slider** in layman terms,  or any web based page or image referring to it.

Answer (score 1):

This laptop (see link in initial post) is delivered with 4 partitions on the drive.

One cannot create more than 4 partitions on a drive. Hence, choosing the automatic 'Install Alongside Windows' option, when attempting to install, causes the system to shut down. Manually partitioning the hard drive is also not an option.

Hence, I had to delete one of the partitions on the drive - I choose the 'HP Tools' partition. I did this step in Windows 7. Then, I simply proceeded according to this tutorial, which includes relevant screenshots.

http://www.linuxbsdos.com/2012/05/17/how-to-dual-boot-ubuntu-12-04-and-windows-7/